# ID10T Check: 6/2 Southwire SIMpull Stranded Is Acceptable for 50 AMP Cooktop Run

Tags: electrical, wiring, kitchens

The 6/2 stranded is about half the cost of solid core (and considerably easier to work with). The run is less than 100' (~70'). Looking at the SouthWire chart, it appears that the 6/2 stranded will work fine for a 50amp 240 run for my new cooktop. I just want an idiot check here to make sure, since I've never used stranded in my years of home-owner wiring.

[This](https://www.lowes.com/pd/6-2-UF-Wire-By-the-Foot/3345386) is the wire I'm looking at (rated for 55A), and [this](https://assets.southwire.com/ImConvServlet/imconv/cc9ee246a3e9a87c880b862c8b599829546d060e/origin?assetDescr=Romex%20Brand%20SIMpull%20Indoor%20Wire%20Copper%20NM-B%20Cable) is the chart I found. I know the wire is UF, but hey, it's cheaper than the NM

Nagging in the back of mind: does the 80% rule apply here?

Edit: Appliance spec wants a 50A circuit @240. 11.1 kW rating (240v)

Comment: How many watts is your cooktop rated for?

Comment: Yes derating applies but it should already be factored in to the "maximum overcurrent protection" spec on the device nameplate. What does that say?

Comment: You really need to give us some more information. Is your cooktop 240/120V or 240V? What is the KW or Amp requirement found on the nameplate of the cooktop?

Comment: Yep, my bad. Added them in to OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The 6/2 stranded is about half the cost of solid core (and considerably easier to work with

Well, there's no such thing as #6 solid.  Wires larger than #10 are required to be stranded.

If you are concerned about cost, ask your AHJ how they feel about aluminum wire at #6 size, and if they're OK with it, use 6-6-6 SER or SEU. This is good to 50A even though it's no larger than the copper. (well actually, copper #6 NM or UF is good to 55A, and all other #6 copper is 65A).  Make sure to use a socket rated for aluminum wire and 75C thermal (the breaker already is).

> Looking at the SouthWire chart, it appears that the 6/2 stranded will work fine for a 50amp 240 run for my new cooktop

Generally, don't rely on cable manufacturers to tell you the ampacity.  In this case they told the truth, but typically they go for the 90C rating or a rating off a completely different chart, and don't mention you can't use that.

> it appears that the 6/2 stranded will work fine for a 50amp 240 run for my new cooktop.

Wait, how are you powering *the oven*?   While cooktops often do not need neutral, ovens need neutral.  Neutral is not ground, and where neutral is required, it must be a 4th conductor.  Use of "/2+ground" to provide 2 hots and a neutral has never been legal.

If there's any probability of this powering an oven in the future, e.g. it's allowed to have a range+oven on the same circuit, then run the 4th neutral wire.

> Nagging in the back of mind: does the 80% rule apply here?

Ranges and ovens don't use that derate.  They use a more complicated derate, which gives some favor to the fact that elements cycle on/off. This is covered in NEC 220.19, but since yours is a single unit, this language applies: "the branch-circuit load for one wall-mounted oven or one counter-mounted cooking unit (cooktop) shall be the nameplate rating of the appliance". So you can go by nameplate with no additional derate.

Comment: Wow, awesome response, thank you! Answers: It's a cooktop, not a range, so they'll be different circuits. And I've never worked with AL wire, so that wades quickly even more into the realm of IDK what IDK... I know you have to be careful to ensure your connectors are OK for bonding dissimilar materials though!

Comment: https://www.lowes.com/LowesProductComparison/50101578,3345386/search/6%2F2/refinement=1 In the case of these two by-the-foot comparisons, why is the UF less than than half the price ($2.18/foot) of the NM ($4.64/foot)? Can I safely use the UF for my usecase?

Comment: @geudrik  The largest terminals are made of aluminum. Balance your comfort zone with your wallet.  You know, we link to box store websites because their product pages are illustrative, but many of us would never advise *actually buying* there, we like real electrical supply houses. Box stores use computers to jack prices as high as the market will bear, they are only a bargain on things they get a lot of price-match requests on or want to feature in the flyer.  I don't think UF is depressed, I think NM is jacked up.

Comment: The cooktop arrived. It's got 8/2 coming out of it... https://imgur.com/a/OIL2itC Appears the ground is "tinned" copper stranded, and the other two are AL #8, per the insulation markings. I guess this goes back to the notion of how cooktop and ovens have a favorable derate due to cycling?

Comment: @geudrik it's because appliances follow UL rules not NEC rules. UL allows different rules because the spaces those wires are in are under engineering supervision, not randomly stuffed in walls and potentially packed or foamed in with insulation.   To couple to aluminum wire, use ILSCO Mac Block Connectors for hot wires, which are miniature Polaris connectors that go #14 to #6.   For grounds use an accessory ground bar intended for a small subpanel.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be good at running #6 on a 50A breaker. You can run up to 165' still be under a 3% drop at that kw rating.

Good luck

Comment: For my own knowledge, can you show me the math for that?